# Why the shortcut doesn't work in my Delphi program?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, action, hotkeys

I've written a program in Delphi 10.4. The main part of the UI is just a TMemo. When the user types something in it, the app will automatically copy the text in the TMemo to clipboard. It looks like this:

[image]

This auto copy part works well. However, I also want to let the user change dark theme or light theme by a shortcut. I enabled a dark theme and a light theme.

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
    System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Clipbrd, System.Actions,
    Vcl.ActnList, Vcl.Themes;

type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
        txt: TMemo;
        ActionList1: TActionList;
        act_change_theme: TAction;
        procedure txtChange(Sender: TObject);
        procedure act_change_themeExecute(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    private
        { Private declarations }
    public
        { Public declarations }
    end;

var
    Form1: TForm1;

var
    is_dark: Boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function ShortCut(Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState): TShortCut;
begin
    Result := 0;
    if HiByte(Key) <> 0 then
        Exit; // if Key is national character then it can't be used as shortcut
    Result := Key;
    if ssShift in Shift then
        Inc(Result, scShift); // this is identical to "+" scShift
    if ssCtrl in Shift then
        Inc(Result, scCtrl);
    if ssAlt in Shift then
        Inc(Result, scAlt);
end;

procedure TForm1.act_change_themeExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if is_dark then
    begin
        TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Windows', false);
        is_dark := false;
    end
    else
    begin
        TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Carbon', false);
        is_dark := true;
    end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    is_dark := false;
    act_change_theme.ShortCut := ShortCut(Word('d'), [ssCtrl]);
end;

procedure TForm1.txtChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
    try
        Clipboard.AsText := txt.Lines.GetText;
    except
        on E: Exception do
    end;

end;

end.
```

However, when I press <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd>, nothing happened. I tried to debug it and I found that <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd> never triggers the action's shortcut. Why this happened? How to fix it? I've used the shortcut function in the past and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `Word('D')`, or the constant `vkD`, instead of `Word('d')`. Shortcuts use virtual key codes, and letters are represented as virtual keys using their capital values. Typing an Uppercase or Lowercase letter into an edit control uses the same virtual key, it is the current shift state that determines the case of the letter when the key is translated into a text character.

Also note that the VCL has its own [`ShortCut()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Menus.ShortCut) function (and also [`TextToShortCut()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Menus.TextToShortCut)) in the `Vcl.Menus` unit for creating `TShortCut` values, so you don't need to write your own function.

See [Representing Keys and Shortcuts](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Representing_Keys_and_Shortcuts), especially [Representing Shortcuts as Instances of TShortCut](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Representing_Keys_and_Shortcuts#Representing_Shortcuts_as_Instances_of_TShortCut).

Also, your `TAction` is clearly placed on the Form at design-time, so you should simply assign its `ShortCut` using the Object Inspector, rather than in code. Then these details would be handled for you automatically by the framework.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know I can assign shortcut directly in the object inspector. It works now. Btw, the link http://forums.embarcadero.com/ in you profile doesn't work.

Comment: @user130268 that is because Embarcadero shut down their forums awhile ago. I'll have to update my profile.

Comment: Where is the most active Delphi forum after Embarcardero shut down its official one?

Comment: @user130268 https://blogs.embarcadero.com/community/. Delphi.Praxis and StackOverflow are probably the most active sites right now